# Where does PHP-FPM and PHP-CLI store the error log?

Tags: php, ini, error-log

When running PHP-FPM or PHP cli if I uncomment the error_log directive - where does PHP store this file?

```
; Log errors to specified file. PHP's default behavior is to leave this value
; empty.
; http://php.net/error-log
; Example:
error_log = php_errors.log
```

I'm asking how `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` figure out the relative `error_log` path.

*Note: This has nothing to do with Apache[1-2]*